# mysql conditional "not_in" based on another value to parse array into query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, case, where-clause

I have the following array

```
$exclude = array(1 => array(1,2,3,4), 2 => array(1,2,3,4));
```

I need to exclude the values inside the inner array when the key validates.  I'm not sure if I should be using `CASE` or just `AND` and `OR`.

Here is the start to what I attempted, but I am missing something, as this doesn't work as intended..  I am appending the query to the end of a `WHERE` clause, so that is the only part I have access to.

```
foreach($exclude as $blogID => $post_ids) {
    $ids = implode(',', $post_ids);

    if($blogID == 1) {
        $where .= " AND table.BLOG_ID = {$blogID} AND table.ID NOT IN ($ids)";
    } else {
        $where .= " OR table.BLOG_ID = {$blogID} AND table.ID NOT IN ($ids)";
    }
}
```

Comment: print the sql query out to see what's wrong with it

Comment: MySQL isn't very good at optimizing complex `AND/OR` combinations like this. It might be better to generate a query for each pair, and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure without having the rest of the query to experiment with, but it may help to add some parentheses around all the clauses to make sure all the ANDs and ORs interact as intended. Something like this:

```
if ($exclude) {
    $where .= ' AND ('; // Enclose all the ORs in one set of parentheses
    $or = '';
    foreach($exclude as $blogID => $post_ids) {
        $ids = implode(',', $post_ids);
        // Each individual OR part is enclosed in parentheses
        $where .= "$or(table.BLOG_ID = {$blogID} AND table.ID NOT IN ($ids))";
        $or = ' OR ';
    }
    $where .= ")";
}
```